# Time Series Forecasting using Artificial Neural Network in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, forecasting

I am new in r programming language, i wanna ask how to conduct forecasting in artificial neural network which has month data as independent variable? How to input month into neural network in r?

Your kind help is much appreciated

Comment: Using neural nets won't necessarily give you better results than an ARIMA or something more traditional. If you're only interested in neural nets you could read this https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/3. It has a good intro on it. Otherwise, if you're interested in time series in general you should read the whole book. It's a very simple intro with R examples.

Comment: Alright, tq! :)